# Python socket.sendto() hangs forever

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Ganapati/Simple-Game-Server) server for my game, but it seems it isn't working properly. This is about the data the server sends to the (receiving) client, basically the last step in the process. I believe this line is causing the problem:

```
sock.sendto(json.dumps({player_identifier: message}), self.udp_addr)
```

It appears to hang indefinetely, "sent" is never printed, but "sending" is. "data received" at the client side is also never printed. The client socket is bound to 0.0.0.0 on port 1235, and the data is sent from the server to the clients ip adress, in this case 127.0.0.1 on port 1235. The message is completely intact when arriving in the send_udp function. I checked all this with by printing it. The run function on the client side is also executed correctly. I couldn't find any usable info on what might be causing this problem, but I suppose it must have worked at one point. Why does sendto not work here? (You can find the rest of the code on the github page in client.py and player.py for the server (maybe also server.py) if you need it)

Server:

```
def send_udp(self, player_identifier, message):
    """
    Send udp packet to player (game logic interaction)
    """
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    print("sending", flush = True)
    sock.sendto(json.dumps({player_identifier: message}), self.udp_addr)
    print("sent", flush = True)
```

Client:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self,
                 server_host,
                 server_port_tcp=1234,
                 server_port_udp=1234,
                 client_port_udp=1235):
        """
        Create a game server client
        """
        self.client_udp = ("0.0.0.0", client_port_udp)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.server_listener = SocketThread(self.client_udp,
                                            self,
                                            self.lock)
        self.server_listener.start()
        self.server_udp = (server_host, server_port_udp)
        self.server_tcp = (server_host, server_port_tcp)
    
        self.register()
    
 class SocketThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, addr, client, lock):
            """
            Client udp connection
            """
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.client = client
            self.lock = lock
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            self.sock.bind(addr)
    
        def run(self):
            """
            Get responses from server
            """
            while True:
                data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
                print("data received")
                self.lock.acquire()
                try:
                    self.client.server_message.append(data)
                finally:
                    self.lock.release()
```

Comment: How big is `message`?  There's a limit to how big a UDP packet can be (although I would expect an error message, rather than a hang, if this was exceeded).

Comment: @jasonharper, Not very big, currently {'name': 'John D.', 'message': "I'm just John Doe..."} as an example and it doesnt work. It also got sent through other sockets first so this probably isn't the problem.

Comment: Perhaps json.dumps() doesn’t return?

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner printing the json.dumps() outputs {"92e4649e-144d-4e01-b272-ded85053dcd7": {"name": "John Doe", "message": "I'm just John Doe..."}}. which is correct I suppose?

Comment: You've changed the philosophy here.  In the git code, the server only receives UDP; all output data goes TCP.  Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @TimRoberts, What do you mean exactly? It uses TCP for server actions and UDP for data transmission, if that clears it up. I didn't change anything functional to the code.

Comment: Ah, you're doing this all on one system?  Remember that only one client at a time can be listening on a UDP port.  If you need bi-directional traffic, then you either need TCP or you need two different UDP ports.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I am using different UDP ports, the loop runs for every client, each on a different port, 1235 for the first, 1236 for the second, and so forth. I also tried it with the server and one client on one system and another client on another and the same problem occured.

Comment: Odd,  Unless you have sent more than 200k bytes before the network is able to flush the data, `sendto` shouldn't block.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I find it very strange as well, also considering it must have worked at some point, or it wouldn’t be in the current state on github. I only sending the data mentioned above (in comments) every 1/60 of a second. I could try to reduce it but I doubt it could be too much. It also isn’t my network because it didn’t work on someone else’s either.